Single Crossing Property - How to prove Neatly
I have the following problem, and want to learn how to proceed in a very precise and short manner to show the Strict Single Crossing Property (SSCP) for $U(.)$ without the brute force approach. I wanted to ask for your help to find how to briefly show SSCP in this and similar settings when faced.
$0<L<w$ and $0<p<1$. $(0,0) \leq\left(x_i, t_i\right) \leq(L, w)$, $u(.)$ strictly concave and $\mathscr{C}^1$ (continuously differentiable once).
$$
U(x, t, p)=p u(w-L+x-t)+(1-p) u(w-t)
$$
$\textbf{(Strict) Single Crossing Property:}$ Let $X$ be a lattice, $T$ be a partially ordered set, and $f: X \times T \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ satisfies the single crossing property in $(x ; t)$ if for $x^{\prime}>x^{\prime \prime}$ and $t^{\prime}>t^{\prime \prime}, f\left(x^{\prime}, t^{\prime \prime}\right)>f\left(x^{\prime \prime}, t^{\prime \prime}\right)$ implies that $f\left(x^{\prime}, t^{\prime}\right)>f\left(x^{\prime \prime}, t^{\prime}\right)$ and $f\left(x^{\prime}, t^{\prime \prime}\right) \geqslant f\left(x^{\prime \prime}, t^{\prime \prime}\right)$ implies that $f\left(x^{\prime}, t^{\prime}\right) \geqslant f\left(x^{\prime \prime}, t^{\prime}\right)$. If $f\left(x^{\prime}, t^{\prime \prime}\right) \geqslant f\left(x^{\prime \prime}, t^{\prime \prime}\right)$ implies that $f\left(x^{\prime}, t^{\prime}\right)>f\left(x^{\prime \prime}, t^{\prime}\right)$ for every $t^{\prime}>t^{\prime \prime}$, then $f$ satisfies the strict single crossing property in $(x ; t)$.
Does it follow from the given assumptions that $U$ satisfies the strict single crossing property (SSCP) in $p$ and $(x, t)$ on its domain? ${ }^1$ If so, prove it; if not add conditions so that it does and prove your assertion. No matter what, assume in what follows that $U$ satisfies the SSCP in $p$ and $(x, t)$.
